# VB.NET How do I store object positions in array?

Tags: .net, arrays, winforms

I want to store object positions in an array to cycle through their positions in a Windows form program.

I have tried:

```
Dim questionPositons As Point = {ButtonA.Location, ButtonB.Location, ButtonC.Location, ButtonD.Location}
```

All responses appreciated.

Comment: Why have you used a "vba" tag for a question with "VB.Net" in the title ?

Comment: Remove the _As Point_

Comment: The only thing obvious from the very brief snippet is that you put it in the wrong place.  You have to make `questionPositions` a field of the class so you can use it elsewhere.  And the assignment needs to happen in the constructor (Sub New), *after* the InitializeComponent() call.  Oh, and it has to be an array, so `Private questionPositions() As Point`.